# How to show specific content based on 3 drop down selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I would like to display a div depending on a user's selection from two drop down lists.

While I'm going to display 3 dropdown options to the users, I'm only going to generate the output based on the selection of the first two:

[image]

This means that I will have a total of 9 possible outputs based on the user's selection:

1. Beaches --> Chill
2. Beaches --> Fast-Paced
3. Beaches --> Both
4. Museums --> Chill
5. Museums --> Fast-Paced
6. Museums --> Both
7. Mountains --> Chill
8. Mountains --> Fast-Paced
9. Mountains --> Both

Just for similar reference, a few months ago, I [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644869/showing-specific-text-output-based-on-2-drop-down-selections) the following script to generate a specific output based on 2 drop down selections:
http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ys3GS/2/

```
<body> 

    <h2>Find your Animal Name</h2>

<p>Select your birth month and your favorite color and find your animal name.</p>

<form>
        <select id="month">
            <option value="">- birth month -</option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>  
        <label class="January" for="January">January Name</label>
        <label class="February" for="February">February Name</label>
        <label class="March" for="March">March Name</label>
        <label class="April" for="April">April Name</label>        
        <label class="May" for="May">May Name</label>
        <label class="June" for="June">June Name</label>        
        <label class="July" for="July">July Name</label>
        <label class="August" for="August">August Name</label>
        <label class="September" for="September">September Name</label>
        <label class="October" for="October">October Name</label>
        <label class="November" for="November">November Name</label>
        <label class="December" for="December">December Name</label>


        <select id="color">
            <option value="">- favorite color -</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
        </select>  
        <label class="Green" for="Green">Green Name</label>
        <label class="Blue" for="Blue">Blue Name</label>
        <label class="Red" for="Red">Red Name</label>
    </form>

  <p id="output"></p>

</body>
```

But this need is a little different. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this? In other words – once the user selected the two options, I want the corresponding div (out of the 9 options) to show up below.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you're ignoring the 3rd drop-down then what's wrong with your existing script, which already works with two?

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing. I think you need to clarify what you want that's different (besides adding another dropdown you won't use for this output).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!! You are amazing. Actually, I would love to create more options if possible using three dropdown menus (and an output of 27). Would that be possible? Also – how would I hide the div when nothing is selected or if you reset the selection? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 9 `div` elements and each `div` element will have two `data` attributes. One for travel preference and one for style. Like so:

```
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="chill"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="fast-paced"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="beaches" data-style="both"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="chill"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="fast-paced"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="museums" data-style="both"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="chill"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="fast-paced"></div>
<div class="result" data-preference="mountains" data-style="both"></div>

<style>
.result {display:none;}
.result.active {display:block;}
</style>
```

Also, let's go ahead and add some CSS to hide these `div` elements, and then setup an `active` class so that we can display the `div` once the user has made their selections.

The select elements where the user makes a choice will have options, and each value will have to be identical to the `data-preference` and `data-style` values. When a user has made a selection in both of the dropdowns we'll grab all the div's and filter out the one that has the matching `data` attributes.

```
$('#preference, #style').on('change', function(){
    // set reference to select elements
    var preference = $('#preference');
    var style = $('#style');

    // check if user has made a selection on both dropdowns
    if ( preference.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 && style.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 ) {
        // remove active class from current active div element
        $('.result.active').removeClass('active');

        // get all result divs, and filter for matching data attributes
        $('.result').filter('[data-preference="' + preference.val() + '"][data-style="' + style.val() + '"]').addClass('active');            
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EFM9b/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!! You are amazing. Actually, I would love to create more options if possible using three dropdown menus (and 27 possible outputs). Would that be possible? Also – how would I hide the div when nothing is selected or if you reset the selection? Thanks so much.

Comment: You can have as many outputs as you like. You will need a separate `div` element containing content for each selection.  

You will also have to be sure that the `data` attribute values match up to the `option` element values. You'll see my option values were identical to the values for each of the `data` attributes. Just have to be sure everything matches up.  

There is a bit of CSS in there `.result {display:none;} .result.active {display:block;}` that will take care of hiding and showing the `div` elements that should not be active.

Comment: Hey @kyle.stearns! Thanks again. I went ahead and tried to set it up:
http://jsfiddle.net/EFM9b/5/

But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea on what's the issue? THANKS SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Take out the spacing and line breaks in your `filter(function(){ .. });`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/kyleva/EFM9b/7/

Comment: You are the best!!! THANK YOU so much for your extensive help. Totally just saved me! Have a wonderful day. Here is the latest Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/t7MFH/

Comment: @Ori Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19504989/144665 it is infinitely expandable, cleaner, and less code than the above answer.

Comment: @Ori The jQuery is faster too as it runs class selectors vs attribute selectors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496884/are-data-attribute-css-selectors-faster-than-class-selectors

Comment: @Ori iambriansreed produced another solution - so take a look. In my opinion it's slightly less clear/straightforward but it gets the job done. Thanks for the additional idea/solution.

Answer (score 2):

The following is jQuery will work for any number of select fields. It uses the values of the options as CSS classes which are then used to match against the results boxes.

No hiding or showing of the results happens until all select boxes are chosen.

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/chnZP/

CSS

```
#results-container > div { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div id='select-container'>
    <select>http://jsfiddle.net/9Qpjg/15/#update
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>    
        <option value='alpha'>Alpha</option>
    </select>        
    <select>
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>  
        <option value='red'>Red</option>
        <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
    </select>        
    <select>
        <option value='none'>Select Option</option>  
        <option value='dog'>Dog</option> 
        <option value='cat'>Cat</option>
    </select>
</div>    
<div id='results-container'>
    <div class='dog red alpha'> Alpha Red Dog</div>
    <div class='dog blue alpha'> Alpha Blue Dog</div>
    <div class='cat red alpha'> Alpha Red Cat</div>
    <div class='cat blue alpha'> Alpha Blue Cat</div>
<div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(function($){

    var
        selects = $('#select-container select'),
        results = $('#results-container > div');

    selects.change(function(){        
        var values = '';
        selects.each(function(){
            values += '.' + $(this).val();
        });        
        results.filter(values).show().siblings().hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Careful naming of your divs will get you most of the way there, e.g.

```
<div class='itinerary' id="beaches_chill">...</div>
<div class='itinerary' id="beaches_fast-paced">...</div>
...
<div class='itinerary' id="mountains_both">...</div>
```

Now show or hide these based on your dropdowns:

```
$('#preference, #style').change(function() { 
  $('.itinerary').hide();
  $('#' + $('#preference option:selected').val() + '_' + $('#style option:selected').val()).show(); 
});
```

(Another answer here suggests using attributes--that's nicer than using the id, so do that.)